# Avro Communication over TCP Sockets

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp, avro

I am currently working on a project that will involve communication of applications written in C and Java. Therefore, I chose to work with Apache Avro. I have seen on the website that Avro can (de-)serialize objects from files using the `DataFileWriter` class.

But, in my case I want to use TCP sockets between my applications. Therefore, DataFileWriter class is not going to work for me. After reading the documentation, I have not  found any information on how to send objects through TCP sockets.

Any ideas on how to do that? I specifically want to know what kind of Input and Output Streams I should use on the Java Clients.

I have developed the following code for the Java Server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashMap;

import middleman.bigpeer.BigPeer;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.BinaryEncoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter;

public class MiddleManWorker implements Runnable {

    private InputStream in;

    private OutputStream out;

    private Socket clientSocket;

    public MiddleManWorker(Socket clientSocket, HashMap<Integer, NodeType> dbNodesDirectory, 
            HashMap<Integer, NodeType>  workersDirectory) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try {
            this.in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            this.out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        EncoderFactory encoderFactory = new EncoderFactory();
        DecoderFactory decoderFactory = new DecoderFactory();
    BinaryEncoder binaryEncoder = encoderFactory.binaryEncoder(out, null);
        BinaryDecoder binaryDecoder = decoderFactory.binaryDecoder(in, null);
        SpecificDatumReader<BigPeer> peerDatumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<BigPeer>(BigPeer.class);
        BigPeer bigPeer = null;
        SpecificDatumWriter<BigPeer> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<BigPeer>();
        try {
            peerDatumReader.read(bigPeer, binaryDecoder);
            System.out.println("Received: " + bigPeer.getType());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            writer.write(bigPeer, binaryEncoder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

A sample Java Client is the following:

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import middleman.bigpeer.BigPeer;

import org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.BinaryEncoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter;

public class SystemClient {

    public static void connect(String serverIPAddress, Integer serverPort) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        /**
         * Create Connection with the server
         */
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverIPAddress, serverPort);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        EncoderFactory encoderFactory = new EncoderFactory();
        DecoderFactory decoderFactory = new DecoderFactory();
        BinaryEncoder binaryEncoder = encoderFactory.binaryEncoder(out, null);
        BinaryDecoder binaryDecoder = decoderFactory.binaryDecoder(in, null);

        BigPeer bigPeer = new BigPeer();
        bigPeer.setType("test");
        SpecificDatumReader<BigPeer> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<BigPeer>(BigPeer.class);
        SpecificDatumWriter<BigPeer> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<BigPeer>(BigPeer.class);

        System.out.println("Before: " +  bigPeer.getType());
        writer.write(bigPeer, binaryEncoder);
        System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
        reader.read(bigPeer, binaryDecoder);
        System.out.println("After: " + bigPeer.getType());
    }

}
```

And the server seems to halt on the `peerDatumReader.read(bigPeer, binaryDecoder);` line of code. Any ideas?

Thank you,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BinaryEncoder uses an internal buffer for performance reasons. You may need to call flush on the encoder to send the data through the pipe.

See the [reference](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/io/EncoderFactory.html) for more information on this behaviour:

> The BinaryEncoder implementation returned may buffer its output. Data may not appear on the underlying OutputStream until Flushable.flush() is called. The buffer size is configured with configureBufferSize(int).
>
> If buffering is not desired, and lower performance is acceptable, use directBinaryEncoder(OutputStream, BinaryEncoder)